# Cookie set by cloudflare are in my website

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, cloudflare, facebook-pixel

I have created a website using `React` with a `Nginx-proxy` and added `Google-Analytics` to analyze traffic.

But, I noticed, there are some cookies that I do not know and are coming from `.cloudflare.com` (with cookies like _biz_pendingA, _biz_sid, _biz_uid, facebook-pixel_*, google-analytics_* etc...).

Please refer to the below image for the full list.

[image]

Can some one explain me why this is happening?

I have a another site that uses `HTML`, `Bootstrap` and `Google-Analytics` using the same `Nginx-proxy` and hosted on the same server, but it does not keep these cookies. So I am puzzled how this happens.

Thank you.

P.s:
I use [Crypto JS](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js) script from Cloudflare to encrypt some data. Can this be the reason for all these unwanted cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit is indeed the [Crypto JS](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js) script from Cloudflare. When I removed it and adds a locally hosted js to encrypt and decrypt, these cookies disappears.

In fact, if you use any of the Cloudflare hosted scripts, they adds cookies of their own to track the traffic.